# Model relationships Django

Tags: django, model, relationship

A bit struggling over here.

So currently I have a model Client and a model Bank. One of the fields in the Bank model is amount. I reasoned as follows: a client can have an account at multiple banks, and a bank can have multiple clients. Hence -> ManyToMany. The problem now is dat I can only specify 1 amount for all accounts a client have... How can I solve this? Create another model? OneToOne? many thanks for the input

Best,

Answer (score 0):

You would want there to be a separation of concerns. So in terms of models, there should be `Client`, `Bank`, and `BankAccount`. There is no need for a many-to-many relationship on Client.

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class Bank(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class BankAccount(models.Model):
    CHECKING = 'C'
    SAVINGS = 'S'

    TYPE = (
        (CHECKING, 'Checking'),
        (SAVINGS, 'Savings'),
    )

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name="bankAccountAsClient", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, related_name="bankAccountAsBank", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE)
```

This way, you can get a clients bank accounts by using `BankAccount.objects.filter(client=client)`

Comment: This *is* a many-to-many relationship; you've just added a few extra fields to the intermediate table that links Client and Bank.

Comment: @EndreBoth true, I meant that he doesn't need the manytomany on `Client`, since he needs the additional fields. Thank you for clarifying

Comment: Indeed. I had overlooked "on Client", apologies.

Comment: @EndreBoth no apologies! I edited my answer to clarify based on your comment. Your clarification is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Hybrid & Endre - Same question for you .. 
.. Do you think I should still need to include a relationship between Bank and Client? Thanks

Comment: @TMD no, that would violate the guidelines of Database Normalization (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). In general, you want as little redundancy as possible in your models/db. Both `Client` and `Bank` are attached via `BankAccount`, so adding another relationship would be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this but might be best to do a model in between both Client and Bank. So call it BankAccount which is what you really want to represent anyhow and it might look something like:

```
class BankAccount(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date_opened = models.DateField()
```

What this does is it now properly connects both the Bank and your Client with pertinent information without having to repeat other data for better "normalization".

Comment: Hi William ! Thanks... Do you think I should still need to include a relationship between Bank and Client? Thanks

Comment: No because you already have "through" this one. Either way, in human terms when you think about it, you should ask the bank account what bank it belongs to, not joe directly. So something like `bankaccount.bank` or in this case `client.bankaccount.bank` should tell you that.